# What file format should I use for rendering?

Tags: rendering, file-format

I am new to Blender and want to render  an image of my object. I see that there are a lot lot lot of file formats to chose from. Which one should I pick?

Comment: Are you rendering an animation or a still image?

Comment: Just one picture

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## Animation

It's generally good practice to render to an image sequence first, then combine all the images into a video format after the render is complete. This allows for the render to stop (whether the result of a crash or just canceling the render to use the computer for something else) and still be able to resume by setting the *Start* frame to the frame after the last rendered and restarting the render.

See [my answer here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/4881/599) for details.

## Stills

As a personal preference I use `PNG` as a kind of default, but each format has it's advantages. The format you use will also depend on what kind of data you need to keep and how much disk space you can spare.

See the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Output#Image_Formats) for descriptions and a list of supported image formats:

> - **BMP**    Bit-Mapped Paint loss-less format used by early paint programs.
> - **Iris**  The standard Silicon Graphics Inc (SGI) format used on some Unix OS machines.
> - **PNG**    Portable Network Graphics, a standard    meant to replace old GIF inasmuch as it is loss-less, but supports    full true color
>     images. Supports Alpha channel.
>
>   Enable the RGBA button to save the Alpha channel.

The *RGBA* option is in *Properties > Render settings > Output*:

[image: RGBA option]

> - **Jpeg**  Joint Picture Expert Group (name of the consortium which    defined it), an open format that supports very good compression with
>     little loss of quality. Only saves RGB values. Re-saving images
>     results in more and more compression and loss of quality.
> - **Jpeg 2000**
>       Uses the Jpeg 2000 codec.
> - **TARGA** and **Targa raw**    Truevision Advanced    Raster Graphics Adapter is a simple raster graphics format
>     established in 1984 and used by the original IBM PCs. Supports Alpha
>     Channel.
>
>   Enable the RGBA button to save the Alpha channel.
> - **Cineon**    format produced by a Kodak Cineon camera and used in high-end    graphics software and more directed toward digital film.
> - **DPX**    Digital    Moving-Picture eXchange format; an open professional
>     format (close to    Cineon) that also contains metainformation about
>     the picture; 16-bit    uncompressed bitmap (huge file size). Used in
>     preservation.
> - **MultiLayer**    an OpenEXR format that supports storing multiple layers    of images together in one file. Each layer stores a render
>     pass, such    as shadow, specularity, color, etc. You can specify the
>     encoding used    to save the MultiLayer file using the codec selector
>     (ZIP (loss-less)    is shown and used by default).
> - **OpenEXR**    an open and non-proprietary    extended and highly dynamic range (HDR) image format, saving both    Alpha and Z-depth buffer
>     information.    Enable the Half button to use the 16-bit format;
>     otherwise 32-bit floating point precision color depth will be used.
>     Enable the Zbuf button to save the Z-buffer (distance from camera)
>     info.
>            Choose a compression/decompression CODEC (ZIP by default) to save disk space.
>            Enable the RGBA button to save the Alpha channel.
>            Because OpenEXR is so new and previews are generally not supported by Operating Systems, enable Preview to save a JPG image
>     along with the EXR image so you can quickly and easily see what the
>     basic image looks like.
> - **Radiance HDR**  a High Dynamic Range image format that can store images    in floating point (with light brighter than 1.0) - 32bits
>     per    channel.
> - **TIFF**   Often used for teletype and facsimile (FAX) images.

Some further notes on a few formats:

- **PNG:** [`PNG`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) (Portable Network Graphics) is a [lossless format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_data_compression), meaning that the data can be reconstructed exactly as it was before being compressed. `PNG` supports [true color](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_Color#True_color_.2824-bit.29) color depth. Blender also supports [16 bit `PNG`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Color_Depth), which gives a larger range of possible colors.

  Because `PNG` is lossless, the *Compression* slider in *Render settings > Output* only affects the file size (AFAIK, the only disadvantage to setting it to `100` is it might take more CPU time to compress/decompress)

  As an example, I saved two pngs, one with 100% compression and one with 0% (Uncompressed). The uncompressed png is 2MB, and the fully compressed png is 18.7KB. The images are identical.
- **JPEG:** [`JPEG`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) is a [lossy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression) format, which means that data can not be reconstructed exactly as it was before being compressed. (see a comparison to `PNG` [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Comparison_to_JPEG)) However, as a result `JPEG` takes up a lot less file size.

  Instead of a *Compression* slider there is a *Quality* slider when `JPEG` is selected as the output format. This refers to how closely the decompressed image resembles the original uncompressed image.

  Here is an example. The left most image is a fully compressed `PNG` (36.3KB), the middle image is 100% quality `JPEG` (20.3KB), and the right most image is a 0% quality `JPEG` (8.5KB). At 1:1 they seem pretty much the same, but when scaled up the differences are more noticeable:

  [image] [image]
- **OpenEXR:** [`EXR`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenEXR) Is a format for [HDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_dynamic_range_imaging) (High Dynamic Range) floating point images, and is capable of storing [deep color](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_Color#Deep_color_.2830.2F36.2F48-bit.29) depth of `32` bits per channel. Blender supports [*Half precision*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half_precision) (`16` bits per channel) and *full precision* color depth `EXR` images (32 bits per channel). As a result, these files can get quite large, especially when using *Multilayer* `EXR`). For example, a `201x167` image saved with lossless *ZIP* compression is `199.1KB`

  These images are good for keeping every bit of data around (including render passes in the case of *Multilayer*), which can be useful for compositing.

---

Note that when rendering a still, the image is stored uncompressed in memory, so you can render an image then save it multiple times in different formats (with different compression ratios).

Comment: Now this is where all of this info pays off.

Comment: You should include how to the compression works for jpeg and quality for png

Comment: also some info on 8, 16, 32 bit would be nice.

Comment: 8 bit gives you 256 shades for every RGB value, human eye cannot see difference between 128, 128.128 RGB and 129.129.129 RGB values, so it is fine when picture needs no editing, 16 bit has 65536 shades, so for example you can change contrast dramatically, and human eye still does not see any difference. 32 bit has 4294967296 shades for every color, which in my experience gives me full freedom of change

Answer (score 7):

In a nutshell this is what I usually use --

PNG 8 bit is fine to save file without any changes

PNG 16bit is fine for some editing in Photoshop/Gimp

Heavy color editing and compositing --  OpenEXR -- has a huge dynamic range

Heavy compositing, animation/movie compositing -- OpenEXR multilayer

OpenEXR multilayer is amazingly powerful format. It allows to keep multiple frames for animation or movie, all/any Cycles rendering passes, and practically unlimited dynamic color range. All of it comes at a cost of huge file sizes. This format is completely supported by Blender compositor, Photoshop does not support it completely at the moment (there is a plugin)

To appreciate what is possible with Multilayer OpenEXR see http://cgcookie.com/blender/2012/12/10/compositing-cycles-render-passes-blender/

Comment: Thanks dimus! Any difference between 8 and 16 bits in just casual viewing? Human eye?

Comment: @NiCkNewman --- for human eye there is no difference between 8 and 16 bit. You can try an experiment of making any two adjacent grey values for example 56/256 and 57/256 --- you will find that your eye cannot distinguish between them. So 8bit is enough dynamic resolution for viewing.

Comment: Thanks Dimus, saved me a lot of bytes from my renders! Thought I had to do 16 :)

Answer (score 2):

Blender's manual has a table of formats supported features, as well as a hint on which formats to use - if you're not concerned with details of each format.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.83/files/media/image_formats.html

Comment: link returns 404 :(

Comment: corrected link.