# How can I animate the Restrict Visibility property of an object?

Tags: rendering, animation

I've been trying to create an animation where an object blinks on and off.

For example, I have a Cube and I set a keyframe on it's Restrict Visibility icon (the "eye" icon) with <kbd>`I`</kbd>, then I toggle off that "eye" so my cube doesn't show in the Viewport and again I press <kbd>`I`</kbd> to record that keyframe. Then, when I preview the animation in the Viewport, I see my cube appears and then disappears like I want, but when I render it, the cube does not disappear at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If one of these answers solved your problem, don't forget to click the ["Solved" checkmark](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_yQeQQ8ImENMnU1ZmpBYjI4WlE/edit?usp=sharing) next to it to let everyone know the question has been solved. :)

Answer (score 10):

### Restrict Rendering

The feature you need to animate is the Restrict Render icon: [image], not the Restrict Visibility icon: [image]. Restrict Visibility only effects whether the object can be seen in the 3D Viewport -- it does not effect rendering at all.

[image]

### How To Render & View Your Animation

1. Before you render your animation, first you should specify where you want the rendered animation to be saved and also the file name. To do this:

   - Go to: Outliner window -> Render tab -> Output section -> specify the directory and file name
   - Select your rendered file output format. Here, I'm selecting the video format MPEG. However, [it's considered very bad practice to render straight to a video file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4874/does-blender-resume-rendering-after-returning-from-hibernation-in-windows-7/4881#4881) -- I'm doing it here only for the sake of brevity.

   [image]
2. Next, scroll down to the Encoding section and select an appropriate encoding format. Here, I'm selecting the MPEG4 format

   [image]
3. Now go up and click on the Render Animation button:

   [image]
4. Now on your computer, go to the place where you saved your file and view it with a video file player:

   [image]

If you want to play your rendered animation directly in Blender, you can use:
Info -> Render -> Play Rendered Animation (<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd>)

**NOTE:** The "Play" buttons shown under the Render Result window will **NOT** play your rendered animation -- they are only for previewing your animation before rendering it:

[image]

You can read more about the different features of the [Outliner window here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Data_System/The_Outliner) and more about the [Rendering Process here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render) in the Blender Manual.

Comment: Thanks for answer, you were correct now when I press render it renders perfectly but I have one more problem. When I try to export this and import in Unity 3d animation doesnt work cube is shown but doesnt disappear ?

Comment: You should ask this in a new question. And I'm sorry, but I've never used Unity before, but lots of people around here have. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for replay. One more thing when I run animation in Blender then Render Resault screen appears, when I press play button animation doesnt work cube is always shown. In process during this rendering it was clearly that cube wasnt rendered at specific keyframe.

Comment: I up voted you answer, because you beat me to it by about 20 seconds. Yes I knew about the `code` styling, but have not used it in a <kbd> element yet.

Comment: @Ivan I'll update my answer to show you how to view your rendered result.

Comment: @Thom thanks for answer, I have done all what you have told me and when I play button in 3d View, Object Mode I can see how my cube appear and disappear. But when I press animation it start to rendering and automaticly puts me in Image Editor where I can see my cube. Then I start animation (Image Editor window is still open) nothing happens it only says Render Result, View, Slot 1, RenderLayer, Combined ? Any suggestion ?

Comment: Ivan, I'm updating my answer now...it'll take me a few minutes and I'll post each step as I write it.

Comment: Ok Ivan, I've finished my answer. Did this help?

Comment: Yes it did thank you very much. My animation was saved in PNG format so I had to include that folder with images.

Comment: Ok, great! Glad I could help! :)

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, don't forget to click the ["Solved" checkmark](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_yQeQQ8ImENOFBILTBzVWdqM3M/edit?usp=sharing) to let everyone know the question has been solved. :)

Comment: BTW, Ctrl+F11 or *Info > Render > Play Rendered Animation* can be used to view the rendered animation from blender. Btw, you probably already know about this, but it's [considered very bad practice to render straight to a video file](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/4881/599).

Comment: Unity3d Doesn't display these keyframe animations. It needs Armature or shapekey animations to display properly (Parented to a mesh).
By the way, you can export yoru model and do the same in unity animation module more easily then blender.
To know about it, Serach answers.unity3d.com

Comment: I propose to cut out the part about "How To Render & View Your Animation" into a new question/answer and then merge my q/a http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16009/animate-the-viewport-visibility-of-an-object-within-the-timeline into here. That would make this q/a complete and less noisy as well :)

Comment: This no longer seems to work in Blender 2.91. When pressing `I` it says "hide_render property cannot be animated"

Answer (score 3):

Simple problem, you are animating only the Viewport Visibility.
In the Outliner, Keyframe the "*Render Visibility*" (camera icon).

[image: outliner showing the buttons]
That image shows an object in the outliner. The three buttons on the right edge are, in order from left to right, *Viewport Visibility*, *Viewport Selection* and *Render Visibility*.