# Animate the Viewport Visibility of an Object within the Timeline?

Tags: animation

I want to hide an object in the Viewport up to a certain frame in the Timeline and then make it visible (e.g. at frame 30). How can i do that?

Comment: I see what you mean. However the other question was about how to achieve this for the rendered animation. I changed this question and answer to describe what to do for the Viewport animation. Is that OK to do ?

Comment: I added a comment into the other q/a and proposed to merge my q/a into the other one.

Answer (score 8):

**Make your Object visible at frame 30:**

You can keyframe the Viewport Visibility of an Object from within the Outliner:

- In the Timeline select Frame 1
- Then open the Outliner
- Set your Object to Hidden
- While the mouse hovers over the eye icon in the outliner, press <kbd>I</kbd> to keyframe the visibility.
- Move on to frame 30
- Click on the Eye icon again to make the object visible
- Then press <kbd>I</kbd> again to keyframe the visibility change.

  [image: control visibility in the Outliner]

Note: If you want to achieve the same for your render, then please check the answer in here: [How can I animate the Restrict Visibility property of an object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8678/how-can-i-animate-the-restrict-visibility-property-of-an-object)

Comment: You might also want to consider the same for the camera to hide it in your render.

Comment: This no longer seems to work in Blender 2.91. When pressing `I` it says "hide_viewport property cannot be animated"