# How can I remove a prop that is used in an action but not needed in another?

Tags: animation, objects

Sorry if this is a newbie question, or maybe I'm not using the right search terms.

I have different action strips for a character, and I'm using props in the first action strip, that are no longer needed in subsequent actions. However I can't seem to remove them without affecting the first strip too.

Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you referring to action strips in the NLA editor?, and if so sounds like they share the same action.

Comment: Yes I am. But within the editor (on the same track), there are different action strips marked out with different animation names and different frame ranges. They're not the considered the same action right? If so, i should just have them on diff action tracks?

Comment: Could copy the action and remove props from copy, use copy in non first strips..  Or split action into two and just have extra props bit in first strip in another track.  Think there is another way but have never got my head around editing actions in strips.

Comment: Thanks batfinger, will give it a try. Another un-neat way i've found is to just move the annoying animation with props strip to another scene, but that seems to result in 2 separate fbx/ blend file - one with props and one without.    Also, my props are meshes created within blender and have its own armature, using 'child of' to animate. Not sure if this info is of any use.

Comment: Can you just animate the visibility of the prop objects?

Comment: Oh thanks! I just googled animate visibility and found this. Gonna try animating changing the props' layer next. Thanks again! https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Animation/Techs/Object

Comment: Mentalist if you'd like to change your comment to an answer I'd be happy to mark it as solved =)

Answer (score 1):

Found something even better! Mentalist gave me much better search terms and I've now found the best answer to the solution. I didn't even know the eye (visibility) icon in the Outliner could be keyframed before =P

Thanks all for the help!

[Animate the Viewport Visibility of an Object within the Timeline?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16009/animate-the-viewport-visibility-of-an-object-within-the-timeline)