# How Do You Select Only Part Of a Timeline To Be Rendered?

Tags: rendering

Let's say I only want a section of the timeline to be rendered, and I want the final output to be in RAW AVI format.  How would you do that? Thanks guys!

Comment: Note that it is considered bad practice to render straight to a video file. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3470/599 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/4874/599.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Specifying Render Output Settings

You can specify a specific start frame and end frame for your render in the Dimensions section of the Render tab:

- Render tab -> Dimensions section -> set Start Frame and End Frame

If your animation is 250 frames long, but you only want to render frames 50 - 75, then set the Start Frame to 50 and the End Frame to 75.

You can also specify your render format to be AVI RAW in the same window:

- Render tab -> Output section -> AVI RAW

[image]

Comment: No problem! Don't forget: if this answer solved your problem, click the ["Solved" checkmark](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_yQeQQ8ImENMnU1ZmpBYjI4WlE/edit?usp=sharing) to let everyone know the question has been solved. Enjoy! :)

Answer (score 3):

The render range can also be set on the tmeline:
[image]