# Why does my frame range start automatically revert back to 0 after I set it?

Tags: rendering

I want to do as described here: [How Do You Start Animation At A Specific Frame?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8901/how-do-you-start-animation-at-a-specific-frame)

Whether I use the setter below the timeline, or the one in the render panel, immediately after I set it--clicking anywhere else--it goes back to 0.  Also trying to set it via the arrows, you can't get past 1, and that also reverts to 0 as soon as you click elsewhere.  Even if I type it in the render panel and the next thing I do is click the anim button (while the typing caret is still there), it has gone back to 0 before the render begins:

[image: reverting animation]

Is there some context in which this is normal behaviour?  If so, how can I change it?

Comment: So, the number in the panel changes back to zero once you start animation? Does do it if you don't type the number in, but use the arrows to increment/decrement?

Comment: Can you give a small screen cast of the unexpected behavior? (See http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers/1056 for help with that, or just add some screen shots of what you're doing)

Comment: @Noidea once I do anything whatsoever, including start animation.  Yes, arrows make it jump 0/1/0/1 only.

Comment: @tschundler done, added an anim.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Never mind, I forgot to mention I'm using an add-on, and with that disabled, this doesn't happen.  So it must be overriding it.

Comment: Which add-on? That's definitely strange behavior. Noting it in your answer here could help people that run into this in the future.

Comment: Well, it's CoaTools, but it may actually be intentional behaviour, I'm not sure.  I already went and opened an issue in its tracker to ask.  I think the takeaway for others can still be "check your addons", because it's not core blender behaviour.