# Blender Cycles quickly renders animation just black

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, animation

After making some improvements to a project that I have not previously had any problems with I proceeded to set up my render settings.

I then realised that I had been working in blender render instead of cycles. I don't know what the difference is between them really apart from I was able to do a lot more in blender render than in cycles.

So I made the changes I needed to make now that I was in cycles render and tried to render the animation. And this happened!!!!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Press "shift + Z" to go into render preview mode, still black? Add a new lamp and a new object to the scene. Render again, still black?

Comment: Is it possible you could upload your .blend? Also, note that it's generally not recommended to render your animation directly to a video file, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/4881/599

Comment: After much searching and reading the advise here I eventually found that I had two boxes selected in Post processing which should not have been.

Answer (score 0):

Cycles Render uses a different node set-up for the materials then Blender Render. (You can check that for both Cycles Render and Blender Render by opening the Node Editor, with 'Use Nodes' enabled) After switching to Cycles Render,  it doesn't contain the materials you have set up in Blender Render. You must make the new materials in Cycles Render yourself.