# smoke+fire simulation fine in viewport but jittery in render

Tags: rendering, physics, smoke-simulation

**[Here's my blend file.](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/36743)** The camera shake is intended.

Here's what it looks like in the viewport:

[image]
<sub>(source: [gfycat.com](http://zippy.gfycat.com/DistinctWellinformedAfricanelephant.gif))</sub>

When I render, however, even *after the camera shakes,* the fire clearly jitters a little bit:

[http://zippy.gfycat.com/WeepyAnchoredJanenschia.gif](http://gfycat.com/WeepyAnchoredJanenschia)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by disabling "Smoke Adaptive Domain" in the Physics tab in the Properties panel, while selecting the domain:

[image: SAD]

For whatever reason, this caused the domain to shake around a little bit, causing the jittering. I'm still not sure why it doesn't jitter in the viewport but does in the final render.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine when I *[Bake](http://blender.org/manual/physics/smoke/baking.html)* the simulation before rendering. I did observe the same jittering when I did not bake first, and let blender calculate the smoke on the fly.

It's aways recommended to bake simulations before rendering, precisely for the purpose of preventing glitches like this.

*Also note that it's also [recommended to render to an image sequence first](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/4881/599), then render that to a video.*