# Rendering Backwards

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Is there a way in ***blender cycles render engine*** to render a scene **backwards** instead of **forward**?

Comment: You mean in terms of frame order?

Comment: Yeah, but some keyframes can't be put in a backwards sequence for example if you are rendering an explosion backwards, so how would you render something backwards instead of foward?

Comment: Is this a workflow question? As in, you decided the end of your animation is a higher priority for rendering than the beginning? Or do you just want it to play in reverse? Because depending on which it is, the solution will be very different.

Comment: I just want to render the animation in cycles as an avi_raw video in reverse using blender

Comment: @AustinH. It's recommended to [render everything to an image sequence before rendering to a video format](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/4881/599). After the animation is rendered it's not hard to reverse the frames by enabling *Backwards* in the VSE

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Once you've rendered the animation to an image sequence, import that into the [VSE](http://blender.org/manual/editors/sequencer/introduction.html) (in a separate .blend if you prefer). To add the image sequence, press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Image* and select the images in the sequence.

   [image]
2. Ensure the scene render dimensions, end frame, frame rate, etc. match your image sequence.

   [image]
3. Set the output settings to render to the video format of your choice.

   [image]
4. Enable *Backwards* if you want to render the frames in reverse order:

   [image]
5. Render (<kbd>F12</kbd>)

Comment: Good answer but not to this problem. OP asked about 'Rendering backwards' not making the already rendered animation play backwards. People want to know how to render backwards because sometimes they need more of the last frames than the first. People finding the question may be frustrated with how the answer is workaround instead of specifically what was asked for.

IMO this was the right answer here: 

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/157143/render-frames-in-reverse?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

In the Sequencer, next to the timeline, on the right lower side of the window, select tab *Strip*.

It's now called *Reverse Frames*:
[image: Reverse Frames]