# Motion Tracking: save tracks but change movie clip

Tags: animation, tracking

I've updated my underlying movie clip (actually an image sequence) and now I want to render a stabilized animation using the existing tracks that I've made. But when I click the folder icon on the movie clip and choose new files, the tracks disappear. Is there a way to restore the tracks to the new clip?

Comment: Could you clarify?... are you trying to see the trackers on a new and different image sequence? or did you just modified the original sequence (replaced a proxy or re-rendered a new version) and want to reconnect your trackers? The trackers are linked to the original video file. You can load other clips on the movie clip editor and the tracking markers will disappear from view, but are by no means forgotten. If you switch back to the original clip the trackers will come back with it.

Comment: I had a jpg image sequence but I want to keep the trackers and change the image sequence to one consisting of png files. The filenames are the same, except for the .png extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load the old JPG (the "proxy" tracked scene)in the Movie Clip Editor, so you have access to the tracking information. Select the trackers toe be used for stablilizing the footage.

[image]

In the compositor create a Movie clip node that uses the new image sequence.

Create a "stabilize2D" node and use the tracking information from the old scene on the new scene.

[image]

Comment: This works well. Before you answered I experimented with copying the tracks and pasting them on the new clip. That also works, but perhaps take more steps. A related question I have is whether it is possible to change the starting frame for the tracks. I would like to insert some frames at the beginning of my clip but keep the existing tracks.

Comment: it is possible, but please ask a new question, so other people can learn from it too.

Comment: Ok, [I've asked here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/11037/change-starting-frame-of-motion-tracks).