# Change starting frame of motion tracks

Tags: animation, tracking

I have a clip that needs additional frames to be inserted at the beginning. I've tried copying and pasting the motion tracks, but they always start at the same frame. I've also tried to edit in the IPO editor but they can only be slid up and down.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.. Trackers are tracked from the current frame. You can track trackers separately too, is that what you want?

Comment: I want to keep the motion of existing tracks, but change the starting frame. That is, take the IPO curves and shift them left or right.

Comment: At the moment It doesn't seem to be a way to slide the motion tracks horizontally on the Dopesheet or within the graph editor of the Movie_Clip_Editor/Motiontrack window. You can insert frames at the beginning of an image sequence if the numbering of the existing sequence is not affected (for example if your previous track started on frame 107 you can add frames before that) however if you are are adding frames before your frame 1 (and have all of the subsequent frames reordered or renamed) there is no way to slide the trackers to line up with the corresponding frames on the previous shot.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to use blender's Video Sequence Editor.

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Sequencer/Usage

You will create a Movie or Image strip from your source clip.  You will then drag it to the right to open up some time at the beginning.  You can then add a strip for the added frames (whether they are an image sequence, movie clip, title card image, or solid color) in that space.

Comment: I'm referring to the Motion Tracking Editor. I need motion tracks to be applied to different frames than they were originally created for.