# Render Quality is amazing but video is poor quality and really grainy

Tags: rendering, animation

When I render my animation I can see each frame being constructed frame by frame and the quality is great, however, when I watch the video that is composed of these frames the video quality is really bad. What should I do?

Comment: Change your video compression settings.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3470/599

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most probable cause for this issue is **bad video compression**. Here are my favorite settings for rendering video.

[image]

I would recommend rendering an image sequence instead though, since that offers better formats such as *.png*

Note:
It is nearly impossible to confirm what is wrong without you posting more information.