# What are these items that are showing up in the viewport render

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, opengl

I have a model that has animation and I am rendering out to a png sequence.
This animation will be used in a web page.

I noticed that there are some items that are showing up in the render that are not part of the model. 
They are vertical black lines with a dashed line/circle at the top that has a solid circle inside that.
They show up in the rendered pngs whether I used material or rendered option in the output view panel.

I've attached an screen grab.

I can't find where these are located in the scene.
I don't know if they are lights or what.

How do I turn them off so they don't render in my png files?
[image: screen shot]

Comment: How are you rendering?  Are you pushing F12?  Those are point lamps, they should not show up in the final render.

Comment: This is an `OpenGL` render I think @PGmath

Comment: @BlendingJake Ah, I kind of speculated that but I never use OpenGL (and have no idea what it does) so I figured someone would correct me!  Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to use OpenGL?

Answer (score 5):

To render just your model without any lights, cameras, empties, or armatures getting in the render; simply turn on *Only Render*.

The *Only Render*  checkbox is in the *Properties* panel <kbd>N</kbd> under the *Display* category.
[image: Only Render]

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be doing an *OpenGL* render which basically gives you a quick snapshot of everything in the viewport. Those "items" are *Point* lamps that light the scene and shouldn't show in a final render that uses correct lighting, aliasing and a world background etc (which I am assuming is what you probably want).

If however you want this quick preview minus the distractions, you can simply hide the lamps by selecting them and pressing <kbd>H</kbd>, to unhide them later, use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>.

To render an image in Blender using the default render engine (Blender Internal) press <kbd>F12</kbd> and to render an animation sequence, refer to [How to render an animation as video in Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15142/how-to-render-an-animation-in-blender). Both these and the *OpenGL* render options are available from the *Render* menu.

[image]

Comment: If he does want to use an `OpenGL` render then you can just hide the lamps and you will still get the light in `Textured` shading, but won't see the lamps.