# How to save animation as a video format

Tags: rendering, animation, export, video

I am basically trying to make an intro for my youtube channel. I am sort of familiar with the program because I was playing around with it for a long time, getting the basics of it. With the help of youtube videos I am basically done with my project. I put my name in it and everything. I just need to know how to save the animation onto my desktop as a file that I could open and would be in a video format.

Comment: You need to render your animation. It's recommended to render to an image sequence first, then render the image sequence to a video file. Specify an output directory and file type (e.g. `png`) and press Ctrl F12 to start rendering. Once done you can press Ctrl F11 to preview your animation (warning, loads the image sequence in ram, so you can potentially use up all of your ram if your animation is long). Then put the image sequence in the VSE, set the output type to the video format of your choice and render again.

Answer (score 15):

Set the Output to "AVI JPEG" in the render settings.

[image]

[image]

Also , to set the place where it is saved , Click next to "/tmp/" , That folder image. Then select where to save. After doing all these steps you can then render and it will appear where you saved it.

## UPDATE:

One of the big changes in 2.79 is that they finally separated containers and codecs.
The encoding options from previous versions are still there, but now they have organized differently

If you select **FFMpeg video**, there will be a new tab for **Encoding** options.

[image]

There you can select the container and the codec for the output file.

[Container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_container_format) is the file format for the file, (Mov, Avi, Ogg, MP4, to name a few) sometimes is referred as a "wrapper".

[Codec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_codec) (short for Compression-Decompression) Is how the image is compressed. The picture quality, file size and processing power needed to view the file are largely determined by the kind of codec used and the settings used for it.

Comment: What if you've already rendered the animation and accidentally saved it in the wrong format. Can you re-save a previously rendered animation in a different format without re-rendering?

Comment: To answer my own question, it looks like you can follow the answer here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15142/how-to-render-an-animation-as-video-in-blender but instead just import the 'mistake' video file instead of the image sequence into the Video Editor, then go back to Default view, set the correct output settings and click 'Animation' to re-export the video in the new format.

Comment: Will this have sound too?

Comment: you can add sounds in the video sequence editor.