# How can I export a Blender Animation as a Video?

Tags: rendering, animation, blender-internal-render-engine, video

I am a newbie to blender. As a part of my coursework I have to do an animation video. I have created  a model, rigged him but now I wonder how to export the animation (pose mode) as a video. There was no proper explanation on it in youtube,vimeo,dailymotion,google.

I am not satisfied with previous below question answer

How to save animation as a video format [duplicate] ([How to save animation as a video format](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23522/how-to-save-animation-as-a-video-format))

Can someone guide me to a video lecture on this or someone please help in rectifying my current situation

Comment: Can you add a few details as to why the question you mention didn't help you? Otherwise, I'm afraid this question is likely to be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Hi I learnt how to export animation as video .In that Previous question it was mentioned exporting each frame as png. What after that is not explained in that question.



A clear explanation is given in layman terms in below tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1qDnZroK28c

Comment: Can someone help me I got another issue. Under Animation Screen layout when I position camera towards my model and render the image.It's not as I expected.

Example: Suppose If I lift my right leg in Rendered Image is showing as left leg. Further if I need to see right body of my model I need to place camera on left side.Help me in rectifying it.

Comment: Please ask new questions for these issues.