# "No layers in render result" - please help :(

Tags: rendering, animation, layers

I'm at my wits' end. I did an animation which was quite a lot of work, then rendered it, disliked it repaired the mesh cause it was all out of shape. Next time I tried to render the animation, I got the "no layers in render result" message and Blender hasn't been able to render even a single frame ever since. First they were all black, now they're all empty. I checked other files which render without problem. I went back to factory settings but still no render so I guess the file bugged out. How can I rescue my mesh, rig and animation? Can I export them somehow?

I have v 2.76 and it never had a problem like this. When I rendered the animation, I followed this tip: [How to save animation as a video format](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23522/how-to-save-animation-as-a-video-format)

Help please. :(

Ok, I uploaded the file. For some reason, the date doesn't get saved properly. I edited it yesterday and today but the date is still March 6.

[image]

Comment: Make sure that you didn't disable any of your renderlayers.

Comment: please edit your question and add images of your render settings, render layers, the outliner window and the post Processing section of your project. Uploading the blend file would make it easier for others to help you. You can use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I feel your pain Kaffeeteria.  Regardless of what your doing in your .blend, I strongly suggest you render out to image sequences first, and then assemble those images in either the Sequencer (in a new .blend) or any program that can turn image sequences into videos.  Rendering straight to video is only ok if you know 100% what the render will look like, but even then, encoding is a tricky thing to get right.  Especially WRT Blender's FFMPEG dependent library.

Comment: Thank you! But that is what I did, following the link above. I rendered the images and put them together. But when I tried to do it a second time, everything broke.

Comment: I didn't put it together in a new file though. I used the original one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Came back to a blender file, now not rendering](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5285/came-back-to-a-blender-file-now-not-rendering)

Comment: You have the **sequencer** enabled in the post processing section. Because of that, the strips on the VSE take precedence and your scene won't render.

Comment: That was it? I just couldn't figure out what I had done wrong. Blender has SO. MANY. OPTIONS. Thank you!! And I'm not the person who posted that other topic. This is the first time I ever posted here. And I'm very grateful for the help. :)

Answer (score -1):

Yes export your file as obj, you have options available to include the animations and other datas

Comment: Hm, I tried that but now I have 78 obj files... I guess I'm too noob for this cause I don't know how to do it right. :( But thank you!

Comment: I'm just telling you what to do, doesn't mean I can do it better than you ^^, There is a way around if you have issues exporting (like I do too), you need to add your horse and armature (and anything you want to save) to a group, then from a new blender file 'append' the group from your original file, I tested it workd with your file without destroying the animation. cheers

Comment: OMG it worked!! The mane is all over the place but I can render again! Thank you so much! And thanks to all the others who replied!