# How do I save a video

Tags: video

I want to save a video file and come back to add more to it later, but every time I try saving it it saves as .blend even though I have it as .mp4. So I'd end up with a file named .mp4.blend. In the output settings I set FFmpeg and h264 in mp4, but it still doesnt save. Help.

Edit: I don't want to render the video yet. Everything I read about of saving a video is by rendering it. I just want to save the file and pick up editing where I left off.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3470/what-file-format-should-i-use-for-rendering/ and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23522/how-to-save-animation-as-a-video-format and

Comment: The blend file is just the project file, where you store the scene, 3D models, and animations (or video strips) that you are working with. When you **save** the file as blend you have not created a single frame of video at all. To generate a video file you have to **render** the animation as a video file. When you render you will be using the settings for FFmpeg and whatever container and codec you want.