# save as a video as .mp4

Tags: rendering, animation, video, file-format

So I made an intro using animation and it saves it as a .blend and I want it so save as a video like .mp4 or something like that.
I've tried changing the codec because I tried opening the intro with windows media instead of blend. I didn't try all the codec's but I tried some of them.

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15142/how-to-render-an-animation-in-blender

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The .blend file contains the 3D project.

To create an animation in a video format you need to **render** it first.

Select the output **format** and **encoding**, the name of the file and hit **Animation** (or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>F12</kbd>

[image]

## UPDATE:

One of the big changes in 2.79 is that they finally separated containers and codecs.
The encoding options from previous versions are still there, but now they have organized differently

If you select **FFMpeg video**, there will be a new tab for **Encoding** options.

[image]

There you can select the container and the codec for the output file.

[Container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_container_format) is the file format for the file, (Mov, Avi, Ogg, MP4, to name a few) sometimes is referred as a "wrapper".

[Codec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_codec) (short for Compression-Decompression) Is how the image is compressed. The picture quality, file size and processing power needed to view the file are largely determined by the kind of codec used and the settings used for it.

Comment: just because this is the top result on google: on **linux**, I had to select `FFmpeg video` in the Output section and then I could select `MP4` is the Encoding section

Comment: Yes, the options have changed in recent versions of blender. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82962/blender-2-79-i-only-get-four-video-output-options/82964#82964