# New blender update doesn't let me render in MP4

Tags: rendering

After Blender 2.79 dropped, I can't seem to render in MP4. I have attempted to use the FFmpeg video option they added, but no matter what I choose in the encoding tab, even presets, the render always ends with a useless unreadable file.[image: File type: file]

Does anyone know what I have to do to fix this?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82962/blender-2-79-i-only-get-four-video-output-options

Comment: The details tab is probably of more interest, as in what codecs are used.  Not an apple user, but  does an extension help, eg "apples.mp4".  It thinks the file is a generic "File".

Comment: Windows won't know what type of file it is unless it has a file extension, rename the file to apples.mp4 and try playing it.

Comment: @sambler lol, really gotta get my eyes checked, that window looked so old school mac to me.

Answer (score 5):

Windows does not understand a file without an extension at the end of the name.

In this case (an MP4) you need the name of your file to be *name*.mp4 for example.

To have blender assign an extension to the name automatically enable **File Extensions**

[image]