# Blenderc 2.79 encoder panel missing

Tags: panel, encoding

The encoding panel is missing. Tried Blender settings reset  then reopened, but still no encoding panel or preview.

[image: missing encode panel Blender 2.79]

Comment: What is "clip preview"?

Comment: "video preview window"

Comment: Different questions should go in different posts.  Since you already created  a [new question for clip visibility](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100486/no-clip-preview) I edited the question to keep things organized.

Answer (score 2):

In the output settings select FFmpeg Video

The Encoding panel will be enabled then..

[image]

Read also this related links:

https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.79/More_Features

[Blender 2.79 I only get four video output options](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82962/blender-2-79-i-only-get-four-video-output-options)

Comment: Thanks... But still no clip preview. Solution to that?