# No clip preview

Tags: interface, video-sequence-editor, video

.blend clip preview missing. Checked settings against another .blend file with active preview and settings are the same. Conundrum... Why no clip preview?

[image: missing clip preview]

Answer (score 1):

One more possible reason, apart what already said by others, it that your video strip has (for some reason) opacity set to zero:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The checkerboard background in the preview indicates that you are viewing a transparent part of video with nothing behind it.

First press <kbd>Home</kbd> - that is above the arrow keys on an extended keboard. If you don't have a full keyboard, it is also in the view menu as *Fit Preview in Window*. This will show the entire video in the preview in case you have zoomed in too far and only a small portion is visible.

Then check that you have something to see. Do you have a png (single image or image sequence) that is all transparent at the current frame? You can *Add->Effect Strip->Color* to fill the video with a solid colour.

The preview channels display option can disable the alpha. I can't see in your screenshot but if the channel number next to that is set to greater than zero you won't see any of the strips above it.

[image: preview channel option]

Comment: Thanks for the help - no image anywhere on clip - not localized to any particular frame or series of frames. Wanted to try & figure it out - it's a puzzle - but taking more time & effort than it's worth. Time to start over and maybe watch a few more Blender tutorials.