# How to save an animation as a video

Tags: animation

I am quite new to blender and am trying to save this small animation I made, I know you can view the rendered animation by pressing CTRL+F12 but how do I save this as a video? Furthermore, when I tried to do it last time and found 400+ images in a blender folder. I have used a gif program to convert these 400+ images into a gif and turned that gif into a video, but is there a directer and more effective way?

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82962/blender-2-79-i-only-get-four-video-output-options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After completing animation in blender, select the Output Folder and Video Format in the right side Properties Panel under Output tab. After that, click on 'Animation' under Render Tab in the same Properties Panel.
https://youtu.be/IIXgRr-lJLg