# Animation Rendered as Images

Tags: rendering

I'm new, so this is probably just a silly mistake, but when I rendered my Smoke Animation(as I followed in a tutorial), it just rendered 250 pngs and not a video of animation. Just confused.[image]

Comment: You can change the file format in the Output panel to a video container and render straight to animation, but most times if using smoke has a transparent background, you will want to render to frames like this and then bring them into the compositor as an image sequence to combine with other footage, or the VSE.

Comment: The answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82962/i-only-get-four-video-output-options