# Why cant I find the Tab in Encoding?

Tags: interface, properties, encoding

I am trying to make a YouTube intro. I have it all done I just need to find the encoding tab in 2.79 but I can't.

Comment: You don't need the encoding panel. Recommend render as image sequence (preferably exr) and encode in any other capable tool like resolve, handbrake or whatever...

Comment: Im very new and have just watched a video how do i do that?

Comment: and when i try to save as it just always converts to a .blend

Comment: Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question.

Answer (score 3):

Select *FFmpeg Video* from the *File Format* dropdown menu, then the encoding panel will be available.

For more detail read the following link:

[I only get four video output options](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82962/i-only-get-four-video-output-options)