# How to render videos for twitter?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I'm trying many configurations to upload a video on Twitter.
Twitter displays the following error message:

"Your media file is not compatible."

Which is the right format and encoding to upload Blender videos in twitter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [save as a video as .mp4](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34586/save-as-a-video-as-mp4)

Comment: even after following all the advice here the only way i've gotten twitter to accept my videos is if i run the file through this website https://cloudconvert.com/mp4-converter i have no idea what the difference is since i'm just converting an mp4 to an mp4. it's funny but it works lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just downloaded video into Twitter with next rendering settings. On the picture below I marked significant properties. Some of them can be set with other values according Twitter documentation I guess. For example fps can be till 40.

In my case it looks like the problem was in audio codec. I did not have any sound so the codec was none. But Twitter require audio codec anyway.

[image: Settings for video rendering]

Comment: That works! :) Thanks a lot Сергей Солуянов! I guess the issue for me was the sound codec...

Comment: The solution works, but in my case I had also to select Lossless in Output Quality settings

Comment: Worked with these settings! Even though my clip was originally 752 frames and didn't get accepted, but when I doubled the speed to 376 frames, it was accepted - very weird stuff...

Comment: It happened again, no matter what settings I used, it didn't work at first - but when I sped up the footage and kept it at 30fps and reduced the length of the clip from 626 frames to 313 frames, it was finally ACCEPTED by Twitter, whee :) (What a weird system they have)

Answer (score 1):

I rendered some videos for Twitter and they worked.
The configuration I used was:

Frames per second: 24

File Format: FFmpeg video

And in the "Encoding" panel I just used the preset "H264 in MP4"

Comment: Hello mugnozzo, thank you for your reply. is it to much if I ask you to upload a .blend file with your configurations? I tried the specs you mention without success.

Comment: Same issue here, these configurations don't seem to make the difference :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the exact settings, but Twitter Developer pages has a list of requirements and recommendations for video uploads:

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/media/upload-media/uploading-media/media-best-practices

See from the "**Video specifications and recommendations**" header in the middle of the page. Maybe your video doesn't have the right framerate or resolution, which aren't a part of format or encoding settings.

Comment: Unfortunately following these guidelines does not seem to give a successful result; there's something missing from this list.

Answer (score 0):

For me, no matter what settings I used, it didn't work at first - but when I sped up the footage and kept it at 30fps and reduced the length of the clip from 626 frames to 313 frames, it was finally accepted by Twitter, yay!