# How to get an mp4 video export format

Tags: rendering, export

Hey all I am stuck I don't know what video format I need to do to export as mp4 in blender animation

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34586/save-as-a-video-as-mp4/34587#34587

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the output format to FFmpeg video and the container to MPEG-4 in the encoding tab (which appears after selecting the output format).

[image]