# Render FPS is low

Tags: animation, video, performance

I looked at the other questions about this, but I'm finding no solution. Partly because I have the newest blender version, 2.76. I am playing my animation back, and it plays around 5 fps. I am using Intel graphics.
[image: Here is the Render settings.]

[image: Here is also a preview of the framerate.]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Slow FPS is a very relative term**. Considering the textures you have and your rig, I think 5 FPS quite a good performance rate.

Note that Blender is not heavily optimized for real-time graphics like a lot of games, and will have much slower animation speed in realtime. You will want to render out your file in order to watch it at the real speed.

*Note: I have had .01 FPS before during simulations*

Comment: I am not closely sure what the frames was, look at the GIF. Do you know how to make it run fast and smooth?

Comment: As I mentioned, you will need to render it out to a file.

Comment: Sorry. I'm a noob. Not sure how to do that yet.

Comment: Try Ctrl+F12, that should render an animation. Also, see this question: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15142/how-to-render-an-animation-as-video-in-blender

Comment: That actually worked out really nice. Thank you!

Comment: No problem! We are glad to help!

Comment: Here: http://i.imgur.com/0mherDr.gif