# Black Glitches on rendered animation

Tags: rendering

I have this sort of glitches all over my rendered animation.

[image]
Could it be a bitrate problem ?

[I reproduced it here](https://mega.nz/#!D981SQ4T!Z8cSOkKvEozvF9JREtDmSn84hs_g0QGZunv2yrSmHcE)

Comment: Can you upload your .blend file to [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)?

Comment: Sorry I can give more infos but not upload it.

Comment: I'll try to reproduce it so I can upload it.

Comment: Done. I replaced the second image with a download link to the project.

Comment: After looking at it, I would agree with @Rawcal 's diagnosis.

Answer (score 2):

I don't seem to be able to reproduce your issue, but seeing you are trying to render directly to video i suspect the problem is in encoding and would strongly advice to render as *image sequence* instead and then render the video from sequence, as described for example in [How to render an animation as video in Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15142/how-to-render-an-animation-as-video-in-blender) , which is better workflow in general as well.

Comment: Thanks you. I'll try this. Even if it's a few... weird that the user has to do so.

Comment: It's actually not weird at all but a better way in almost any sense. Image sequences are safe from software crashing mid-render and don't have any compression loss making them better for post processing. Also image sequence can be rendered to any video format in original quality without having to rerender the 3d scene.

Answer (score 1):

Those random blocky artifacts are most likely an issue with the GPU.
[image]

The tile size you are using (512) might be too large. Try a smaller value.

[image]

I'v also seen those problems when the GPUs get too hot or reach the end or available RAM.

The best way to deal with this is not using a video format to render, but render as an image sequence. That way if you have one frame with artifacts you just re-render that one, but keep the rest of the frames that have no issues.