# How to render a final edited video

Tags: rendering, animation, video

So, here's the deal. I have a few clips and transitions in my sequence editor that make a complete 20 second video. Now when I save it, it's saved to my output folder as a BLEND1 file. I need to convert/render it to either an AVI or MOV, basically something I can upload to YouTube. Not sure how to do this. Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: I'm not really sure this is a duplicate, but it's definitely related, and the top answer has the information you need. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15142/how-to-render-an-animation-as-video-in-blender

Comment: You are not saving the video, you are saving the blend. You need to RENDER the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

you need to RENDER your video - use the "properties" panel for this.

PS.- don't forget to check the "sequencer" and uncheck the "compositor" under "post processing".

Comment: Also make sure you set the "Output" value to a easily find-able location, and the correct number of frames.

Comment: Thanks everyone! This was a really big help and I figured it out. :)