# How do I render and save as MP4?

Tags: rendering, animation, blender-internal-render-engine

I am using the latest version of 2.78a and I can't figure out how to save it as an MP4 file. I have downloaded an intro template (for youtube) and changed the text to what I want, but I don't know how to save it as an MP4 file. I have rendered the animation on default settings and it keeps rendering the animation over and over again. What do I do?

Comment: Related; https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15142/how-to-render-an-animation-as-video-in-blender

Comment: It many cases it is better to render to PNGs and then use a separate tool to encode it to mp4 : http://web.purplefrog.com/~thoth/blender/python-cookbook/render-to-pngs.html

Answer (score 2):

Blender will render the frames that are between the *start frame* and *end frame* if you press *Animation*.

The outputfile is located in the path that is shown in the text-box. You can change it pressing the button with the folder icon

You can either the animation as an image-file sequence or as a video file. MPEG will output .dvd format, but you can change the extension to .mp4 in the windows explorer (you must check the option to view the file extension in *folder options* from windows

[image]

Comment: Ok, ive pressed the text button box at the top of the screen and the only other option is trapcode. Also, why does the nimation keep rendering over and over again? And i can't locate the folder icon. I want to have the animation as an intro for a youtube video in MP4       *EDIT* i now understand why it renders over and over again - it has to render every frame of the animation, like you said, i apologise. but i still don't know what to do when it is is finished rendering. do i have to wait for the rendering to finish before the mp4 option becomes availible?