# What is this rendering bug?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

So, I rendered a scene with a 2D plane and an ortho camera with a mask object. But when i render it (Blender Internal), it gives me this. It gives me this bug when I import the scene to the VSE, and render it in the VSE, it gives me this bug.

[image: this is a still shot from the rendered video]

How do I solve this? Any ideas? thanks for your help!

Here's the blend file:

[image]

Comment: Screenshots of VLC don't help solve Blender issues

Comment: how do i upload videos then?

Comment: Are you using Blender Internal or Cycles? Do you obtain the same result in the Viewport in the "*Rendered*" mode (Shift+Z)? Can you share a screenshot of your setup or, even better, your blend file using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com? Please edit your question to add this information so that we have a better idea on how to help

Comment: Im using blender render, not cycles

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5215/

Comment: I tried your file, the animation renders perfectly here. Even if I render it (png sequence) and then import the sequence to the VSE.

Comment: @m.ardito nevermind, I already sorted it out

Comment: Ok, well done! You could add an answer below, adding something about what it was, how you solved, this could  help other users in future having similar issues...

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how you rendered the video, since the blend file you have provided is set to render as separate `png` still frames:

[image]

Rendering it with the *Animation* button (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd>) works fine on my computer so I can't reproduce your issue and I believe it might be related to the extra steps you took to actually make the video.

I suggest you keep rendering as still frames (like in the file you uploaded), but to change first the "Output" directory to something which is not a temporary one.

After it has been rendered, check that your output frames look good, and finally merge them into a video (you can do it with external applications, or within blender following steps 3 to 6 from this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15145)

Comment: I rendered as mp4, is it a hardware related bug

Comment: Also, I forgot to say that I imported the scene to the video sequence editor, then rendered it from there.

Comment: please make your question complete with all the relevant info if you want to get an useful answer

Comment: edited the question

Comment: so based on my updated question, do you know the problem?

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I still struggle to understand what route exactly you did follow. I've given my attempt at an answer, which as I understand you don't find suitable. Hopefully someone else on the site will be able to help you