# Rendered as PNG, how to play it as a mp4

Tags: file-format

im new to blender and i need some help. i recently rendered a project that took 5 hours to render. i rendered it and it filled my folder with images. i can play the finished render in blender. but what if i want to upload it to youtube? i have a ton of images but can play them like a mp4 etc... any way i can make a mp4 without having to re render everything? i could put all the images in a video editor but thats hassle. is there no easy way to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to render an animation as video in Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15142/how-to-render-an-animation-as-video-in-blender)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the Blender's VSE window and add an image, then select all the PNGs: they will be automatically loaded as a sequence. You can render out this sequence as mp4, and the render time will be very short,

Answer (score 0):

You should use ffmpeg.exe to do this instead of blender at this stage. Once the material is out of blender in a finished format, it shouldn't be tossed back into blender. For the reason that 1) blender always re-encodes 2) blender vse has limited post-processing tools 3) blender renders using a single cpu core, aka its always stupidly slow.

In your post you said you *didn't* want to re-render again. Depending on your image format you don't have to with ffmpeg.exe. For example if you had png strips you could copy and store those in a matroska container. Although blender uses ffmpeg to do its renders, it forces re-encoding on all its operations and lacks the options that the ffmpeg.exe can offer you. So for example the same operation can be done in blender in this case but its 100x longer and much more of a hassle and it forces re-encoding and artifacts...degrading ur picture quality unless your png had 16 colour bits.

If you plan on using blender as a vse I highly encourage you to compliment it with ffmpeg.exe. if you want a good place to start to learn: https://amiaopensource.github.io/ffmprovisr/