# How do I save my output blender render file as a mp4? (Blender 2.80 Beta)

Tags: rendering

So I was rendering on Blender 2.80 beta, and I don't know how to save the render files from an a animation.

I setup my input and output areas and still no output file from the animation render.

I'm also using EEVEE

Comment: Are you using the compositor (as you mentioned using Input)? You have to make sure that the Output Node is connected and that you have chosen an ffmpeg output type in the render settings of the scene tab.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information on how you set up your project. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that might help us understand your scene settings and the nodes you are using.  See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: Read [How to export a blend file to mp4](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/142528/how-to-export-a-blend-file-to-mp4/142548#142548)