# How to export my .fbx file as an .mp4 file

Tags: rendering, export

I have created a 3D animated character in Mixamo and uploaded the .fbx file into Blender. What steps do I need to take to export it as an .mp4 file (Maybe there is a tutorial I could watch?)

I'm new to 3D animation and Blender so any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Hi there : ) .mp4 is a video file format while .fbx is a 3d file format . As far as I know, u can 't convert a 3d file format to movie file like mp4 you. However u can change it to other 3d formats like .obj , .max etc.

Comment: Thank you Nxdhin2005 I will try converting my .fbx file to .obj

Comment: What you are looking for it's called rendering. You have to add a camera and probably a light source and render a video.

Comment: +1, @FFeller , that's right , you can change your animation into whichever video format you like. But not the 3d object

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15142/how-to-render-an-animation-as-video-in-blender

Comment: Hi All, I think what I am looking for is 'How to render animation to individual frames'. My understanding is the individual frames can then be used to create a video within Blender or uploaded to Premiere Pro.