# Blender video to .mp4

Tags: export, edit-mode, video

I'm very new to blender and are using it to edit videos. I slapped 2 osu clips and a end card together but for some reason it only wants to save as a .blend file.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15142/how-to-render-an-animation-as-video-in-blender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the appropriate setting in the "Output Properties":

[image]

- Set File Format to FFmpeg Video
- Container to MPEG-4
- And Video Codec to H.264 (others also work, but use this one if you don't know the difference.

Another tip is to turn of "File Extensions", and manually type in ".mp4" at the end of your file. This way Blender wont auto name it as "MyeVideo0001.mp4

After the settings are correct and you want to save it as a video, you need to render out the video. And video should be rendered out to the location specified in you output settings.
[image]

You can read more about the settings over here:

- [Output Panel](https://docs.blender.org/manual/es/2.79/render/output/output.html#output-panel)
- [Encoding Panel](https://docs.blender.org/manual/es/2.79/render/output/video.html)

Comment: deleted my answer because yours was more fleshed out. nice job.