# My render output become just a file

Tags: rendering, error, blend-files

I've just render a animation scene for a day then this happen!!! Please help me fix this...

[image]
[image][image]

Comment: what do you mean "this happens"? You've chosen JPEG as file format, so your animation is rendered as a series of images, not as a movie, you need to choose a movie format (like Ffmpeg) if you want a movie

Comment: now that you have an image sequence, render the sequence in the VSE...read [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15145/15924)

Comment: Since this is windows, the reason why the individual files don't appear as images in the browser is probably because either the file association for jpg extension is wrong or the files were created with a wrong extension.  Fix this to get the files to look right in the browser and then use the VSE as @Timaroberts suggests to turn the output into a movie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just enable the "File Extension" option, then Blender will not only write you a nice image file, but also append the file name extension.

[image]