i cant save as ffmpeg


i am completely new to blender and i was using it to do a project of mine
i am rendering the animation and i am using the setup below,
but when 1 press render animation it comes up as jpg?
i really dont know what im doing
i am using the evee engine and my animation is 350 frames long and i uses the f12 control button to render

Hello and welcome. You need to give more info about how are you rendering your scene. Using the Render menu > render animation or is it CTRL +F12?

In the pop-up viewer, you'll see what looks like individual jpg's, but but in your C:\renders\ folder you should see an output 000-[END_FRAME].??? being created.  So check there.

i uses the f12 control button to render that is an unusual phrasing, do you mean that you use Ctrl F12 or just F12?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15142/how-to-render-an-animation-as-video-in-blender Looks like a duplicate if the answer below is the solution


F12 will only render a single frame and show it in the render result.
If you want to render an animation, you need to use ⎈ CtrlF12, which will render each frames in the frame range and save them as it goes.

That being said, about using a video output, I would think about it more if I were you.
Video files have two massive disadvantages: they require more computing power to be made (so you create a competition for resources between rendering and video encoding), and they can't be easily recovered or fixed if anything bad happens during the render. And unless you render raw files that are massive in size, or use high compression quality that take massive amounts of time and resources to encode, your final results will be full of rendering artifacts.
If you crash during render, many video formats would just give you an unusable video file, and you would need to re-render everything. If you did finish your render but have a few frames to retake, you would need to either render the retakes and then do a video editing and re-encode (losing quality) to fix the frames, or re-render everything again because you would have too visible compression artifacts with a fixed patch or after re-encoding. And in regular formats, you don't actually get access to each and every frame nor to all the original colors of the render, so any further editing will be very limited.
Hence, IMHO there's only one scenario where a video output has any benefit: if it's a quick preview render, low resolution, that renders fast, and is of no importance, and you get the convenience of having just one file which you can open in most video reading softwares.
Meanwhile, an image sequence is entirely versatile: if you crash during the render, or even if it's just you wanting to pause the render, you can. All the rendered frames are already saved, no data loss here. If you need to re-render a few frames for any reason, it's as simple as that. You can also easily distribute the render on multiple computers to speed up the whole rendering. You can save images with linear color space to do extensive color grading later, you get to access absolutely every frame as they are, you can use EXR multilayer to have render passes included in each frame file.
But it does mean that you can't read this without either specialized software or a video editor. But Blender comes with both...
As for an ideal image format, just avoid PNG and JPEG. There's a nice image format comparison here: rendering - What image format encodes the fastest, or at least faster? PNG is too slow - Blender Stack Exchange
