# I get a "Width not divisible by 2" error when I render

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, video

I can't seem to figure out what this is talking about. I've tried to change my settings, but nothing works.

This is what it says.

[image: error message]

These are my settings. I can't find anything that is 1171x658.
[image: render settings]

Answer (score 23):

You actually do have your render set to 1171 px wide.
Look at the *"Percentage Scale"* value directly below the width and height under the [Dimensions](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/output/output.html#dimensions) category of the *Render* tab of the properties window. It is set to 61%, and `1920 x 0.61 = 1171.2`.

Simply set the *"Percentage Scale"* to 100% and you will be rendering at the expected 1920 by 1080.

Answer (score 6):

Some output encodings, especially the highly compressed (e.g. h.264) encodings, have special requirements, 
i.e. width/height need to be divisible by 2 or even 4.

Your width is (rounded) 1171, use a slightly different "Percentage Scale" value
as described in the other answer or change the [output format](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3470/what-file-format-should-i-use-for-rendering).

Answer (score 1):

i had this problem and solved it myself, your percentage scale is an odd number so it is not divisible by 2, if you want to keep your per scale just change it to 60 or 62