# Animation fade to black?

Tags: animation, video

I'm making an animation and at the end I want the screen to fade to black. Is there a way of doing that with an animation? Or do I have to first render the animation and then re-open it when it has been made into an MP4 and then import back into the video editor, add the fade to black and then render it again in the editor? That seems like a lot of work for something so simple.

Comment: Once you've rendered to mp4 any change will mean re-encoding meaning a loss in quality. Render your animation as an image sequence, load that into the VSE and do the fade out there, then encode to mp4

Comment: I just had a thought. Putting a big black invisible cube over the camera and then animate the cubes transparency to 1 towards the end? ;D

Comment: No need to re-invent the wheel, just animate the opacity on the scene strip on the vse.

Comment: What does VSE stand for? Is that Valve Source Editor? That's what I know it as ;D

Comment: Video Sequence Editor. Read: https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/sequencer/index.html

Comment: when you said render them as an image sequence did you mean render them all as PNG?

Comment: What I mean by image sequence is "a sequence of numbered independent images not compressed in a video format". Png is one of the possible options you can output from blender.

Comment: cegaton is saying that it's best practice to render out as image sequences initially, regardless of the image file format.  You can always assemble the images in the VSE later to convert them to a movie format.  It can be PNG, or any minimal loss image format, such as tif.  This is partly because this can minimize the picture quality loss normally associated with various video codecs at an early stage of rendering, and if Blender/your computer crashes during rendering, you can pick up where you left off if those images have been saved to your HD.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3470/what-file-format-should-i-use-for-rendering/3472#3472

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fade-to-black can be achieved in Blender if you feel like third-party video-editing software is not optimal, or the most succinct.

1. Assemble your image sequence/movie file into the Sequencer.
2. Scrub to a part in the timeline where you'd like to begin fading to black.
   [image]
3. Goto to Sequencer menu, click `Add` -> `Effect Strip` -> `Color`.  (It defaults to Black, but you can make it any color).  *Note* this strip should be on top of your image sequence/movie file.
   [image]
4. Select this color strip, and hit `N` to examine its properties over on the right.
5. Find the `Opacity` settings just in the `Edit Strip` section.
6. Scrub to the beginning of this Color strip.
7. Set the opacity to 0.  With the cursor over top of the slider, hit `I` to keyframe it.
8. Scrub to the end of the Color strip.
9. Change the opacity, this time to 1.0, and with the cursor in the slider field, hit `I`.  The color's opacity is now interpolated over the duration of the strip.

[image]

You can also fine-tune the interpolation like any keyframe by opening this strip in the F-Curve editor.  Happy editing!

Comment: For a simple fade out you can just animate the opacity of the strip.

Comment: ...That's very true!  Fading to 'pure' alpha translates to black in video output anyways :P

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question. Muly's question is to do a fade from it's 3D scene directly to black. Not to do it on images or movies.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to fade from a 3D scene with animation to a black screen thanks to `scene` strips, but to do that you need to create seperate `scenes` in your blend file.

- One `scene` containing your 3D scene
- One `scene` in which you will do the video editing

You can create your scenes at the top right corner above the Outliner:
[image]

Then select your video editing scene and go to the `Sequencer`. Click on `Add` > `Scene` > select your 3D scene.
[image]

Add a new `Color` strip. Click on `Add` > `Color`. Then right click on the `Color` strip > `Fade` > `Fade in`
[image]