# How to render an animation with Render Layers?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, render-layers, layers

So, I heard some people recommending rendering an animation in layers to render faster and save on memory.

So I have attempted a simple scene(.blend included) where I have three Render Layers. One called "Plane", another called "Objects" and finally one called "Cube".

The scene has a plane to act as a floor, some objects and one of them is a cube. The cube has a simple animation of moving from one side to the other with it's shadow interacting with the floor and the objects. All of these elements are on their own render layers.

When I tried to composite them, I noticed that the Ico-Sphere is no longer clipping trough the floor(plane) which is not what I want.

This picture shows you what I mean. The Ico Sphere is suppose to be going trough the plane but when I composited it put it on TOP on the plane which is not what I want.

[image: Obects clipping]

What I also tried to do was to render it out as an EXR file but the files came out black showing nothing at all.

Any further help on this would be very appreciated.

[image]

Comment: It is possible and advised, you should probably render frames to Multilayer EXR. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16152/save-all-render-passes-to-a-single-exr-image/18406#18406 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3470/what-file-format-should-i-use-for-rendering/3472#3472 If these don't answer your question please edit your post and add more information so we can reopen it

Comment: Unfortunately that answer wasn't enough so I've added more information to my question so you can reopen my question.

Answer (score 0):

because the icosphere and the plane are in different layers, they dont interact with each other. You can either:
1- have the plane and the sphere in the same layer
2- duplicate the plane and move it to the object layer, and make it a shadow catcher and a holdout in Object Properties > Visibility