# Power went out. Render was abruptly ended. Can I resume rendering?

Tags: rendering

It was almost done, the movie file is corrupt and can't be opened. How do I fix this? It was a 3D VR render in current version. Can I fix it? I don't want to rerender for a week...

Comment: [Never render 3D directly to video](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3470/what-file-format-should-i-use-for-rendering/3472#3472)

Comment: Your question based on the title could be answered with yes, but then your text gives information and asks if it's possible to fix, based on the details you give i very much don't think so. In movies they have such sophisticated software, if you find something like that, please let me know. Til then, i highly recommend to read the linked information by @DuarteFarrajotaRamos and in the future use image sequences to render big projects.

Comment: If.you were rendering video, then  most likely you have to start over. That is one of the main reasons why you never render directly to video, but to an image sequence first