# Save PSD (or TIFF) with passes as layers?

Tags: render-layers, render-passes

I wonder if there is any way in Blender for saving render results in PSD (from what I can see it is not supported) or TIFF file with layers from passes (for example refletion pass, object id, material id pass and so on)?

I know that it can be done with compositor, but the problem is that I`m looking for a fast workflow for hundreds of files and in general I need to put all those passes into photoshop layers anyway. So struggling with compositor is not an option for me.

Comment: Hello :). I don't think so, as PSD is a proprietary closed format. You can use Open EXR Multilayer and then import it into Photoshop. There's no struggling with Compositor, you simply choose which passes to include :).

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16152 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3470

Answer (score 5):

Wow! I think I figured it out. You need to use OpenEXR Multilayer file type when saving and install EXR-IO plugin (free) for Photoshop (https://www.exr-io.com/features/).

Comment: Exr is the only format that will keep your scene referred information linear. Other formats will require you to do all kinds of scaling , converting and reconverting. Think of EXR as a way of keeping and transporting the render layers intact.