# How to export after compositing?

Tags: export, compositing-nodes

I'm new to blender (and 3D art in general) and I'm wanting to know what to do after I've finished rendering my animation (as an MP4), and compositing it. I've watched at least ten different compositing tutorials, not one of them ever explained what the next step is. Do I "render as animation" again? Or is there some special way of finalizing and exporting your animations after you've finished composition? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You 't normally [shouldn't render from 3D scene directly to video](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3470), for a variety of reasons. When compositing you often composite from image sequence format to publishable a video format